# How can I display the details from a parent object in a child input form with Angular Material?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-form-field, angular-input

I'm trying to display a object from a parent table in a child form input field with Angular Material. But it doesn't display the object values in the input fields. It only displays the `<mat-label>` that I have created. I have tried add placeholders with property binding but that result to a error.

this is my code:
**parent-template.html**

```
<table class="mat-elevation-z8 table table-primary table-striped overview-no-margin">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Product Tag</th>
    <th scope="col">Product Status</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr (click)="onSelect(product)"
      [class]="selectedProduct === product ? selectedProduct : null"
      *ngFor="let product of products">
    <td>{{product.tag}}</td>
    <td>{{product.status}}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button (click)="addRandomProduct()" class="addProduct btn-lg btn-primary">Add Product</button>
<app-product-detail [showProductDetail]="selectedProduct"></app-product-detail>
```

**parent-template.ts**

```
export class ProductEditComponent implements OnInit {
  public selectedProduct?: Product;
  public products?: Product[];
  // public  defaultRow?:number = 8;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.products = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++){
      this.addRandomProduct();

    }
  }

  public onSelect(product: Product): void{
    this.selectedProduct = product;
    console.log(product)
  }
}
```

**child-template.html**

```
 <div *ngIf="showProductDetail" id="product-detail">
      <form class="product-detail-panel mat-elevation-z8" >
        <div id="detail-header">
          <span><b>Update scooter </b></span><u>{{showProductDetail.tag}}</u><b> with scooter ID: </b> <u>{{showProductDetail.id}}</u>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <mat-form-field class="product-tag" appearance="fill">
          <mat-label>Tag:</mat-label>
          <input matInput [(ngModel)]="showProductDetail.tag" >
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field class="product-status" appearance="fill">
          <mat-label>Product Status:</mat-label>
          <mat-select [(ngModel)]="showProductDetail.status" >
            <mat-option value="STOCK">STOCK</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="OUT OF STOCK">OUT OF STOCK</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="COMING SOON">COMING SOON</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="NOT DELIVRABLE">NOT DELIVRABLE</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="ON SALE">ON SALE</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field> 
</div>
```

**child-template.ts**

```
export class ProductDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() panelMessage = 'Select a product from the left panel:';
  @Input() showProductDetail?: Product;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have solved this issue with the following  code, the true standalone shows the inner value you need in a form.

**Child-template.html**

```
div *ngIf="showProductDetail" id="product-detail">
      <form class="product-detail-panel mat-elevation-z8" >
        <div id="detail-header">
          <span><b>Update scooter </b></span><u class="product-tag">{{showProductDetail.tag}}</u><b> with scooter ID: </b><u id="product-id">{{showProductDetail.id}}</u>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <mat-form-field class="product-tag" appearance="fill">
          <mat-label>Tag:</mat-label>
          <input matInput [(ngModel)]="showProductDetail.tag" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field id="product-status" appearance="fill">
          <mat-label>Product Status:</mat-label>
          <mat-select [(ngModel)]="showProductDetail.status" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
            <mat-option value="STOCK">STOCK</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="OUT OF STOCK">OUT OF STOCK</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="COMING SOON">COMING SOON</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="NOT DELIVRABLE">NOT DELIVRABLE</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="ON SALE">ON SALE</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a tricky one, since the logic you have in your code it correct. But let's try this:

a) In you child-template.html code, the  tag doesn't have a closing pair. Add it as see if it fixes the issue.

b) Make sure that you have all the needed module imports, eg.

```
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
```

c) if none of the above work, please give more info on the error you mentioned here: "I have tried add placeholders with property binding but that result to a error.".

Comment: Thanks for the help and quick reaction